# Escape HTML in dynamic box title of shinydashboard

Tags: html, r, shiny

I want to dynamically change the title of a `box` in a `shinydashboard` based on `selectInput()` selection but I cannot escape the `HTML`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(htmltools)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    selectInput("plottype", "Select plot type", c("AP:TOTAL","FF:TOTAL","OVERALL")),
    box(title=paste(htmlEscape(textOutput('box1title')),"charts"),
        width = 6,
        solidHeader = TRUE,
        status = "primary",
        p('Use the checkbox to change the title of this box.')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$box1title <- renderText({
    if(input$plottype=="AP:TOTAL"){
      "AP:TOTAL"
    }
    else if(input$plottype=="FF:TOTAL"){
      "FF:TOTAL"
    }
    else{
      "OVERALL"
    }
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't to the `paste()` in the UI, do the paste in the server function

Just use the plain test output for the box title

```
box(title = textOutput('box1title'), ...)
```

And  then in the server do

```
output$box1title <- renderText({
    part <- if(input$plottype=="AP:TOTAL"){
      "AP:TOTAL"
    }
    else if(input$plottype=="FF:TOTAL"){
      "FF:TOTAL"
    }
    else{
      "OVERALL"
    }
    paste(part, "charts")
  })
```